# How to select a specific line in a row with carriage returns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, carriage-return

Using SQL Server 2012 I'm running the following basic query

```
SELECT  MacroID
      ,MacroText
      ,AuditEventID
      ,AuditTypeCode
      ,AuditTimestamp
  FROM APXFirm.dbo.AdvMacro
```

However it's come to my attention that every result row has numerous carriage returns embeded, and I need a specific row within the rows.

Below is how the result set looks in SQL.

[image]

However when pasting it in Notepad it'll look something like this.

```
[Version] 3.5.1.212
[Description] TaxLot information for populating Holdings table
[Portfolios] @master
[Mode] Management
[AutoPrint] No
[Graph] No
[Sheet] No
[Attended] No
[Apply Copies] No
[Page Number By] Report
[Number One Page Reports] No
[Consolidate Composites] Both
[Frames] Yes
[Output File] TxLotExt
[Error File] TxLotExt
[Report]  txlotext.rep Report txlotext.rep
$prifile 123103
$_outfile TxLotExt.xml
gauge 2 1
prop MB
frame g1 2 c y y y "Report txlotext.rep" y - y y 0 0 100 100 000000 ffffff 0 1 "" ffffff 000000 360 0 0 6a240a n
frame g0 2 r n n y "Report txlotext.rep" y - y y 0 0 100 100 000000 ffffff 0 1 "" ffffff 000000 360 0 0 6a240a n
```

What I need is lines that begin with [Report] including the brackets, but I need the information that follows.

```
txlotext.rep Report txlotext.rep
```

I'm not sure how to query a row within a row.

Comment: is "[Report]  txlotext.rep Report txlotext.rep" this the text you want to 'extract'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  MacroID
      ,MacroText
      ,AuditEventID
      ,AuditTypeCode
      ,AuditTimestamp
     ,LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(
       RIGHT(MacroText,LEN(MacroText) - CHARINDEX('[Report] ',MacroText) - LEN('[Report] ')),
       CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),RIGHT(MacroText,LEN(MacroText) - CHARINDEX('[Report] ',MacroText) - LEN('[Report] '))) - 1
       ))) as DesiredLine
  FROM APXFirm.dbo.AdvMacro
```

Use a combination of CHARINDEX(), RIGHT(), LEFT(), and/or SUBSTRING() to find what you want and cut up the string.  CHAR(13) is carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- create sample table 
use tempdb

create table dbo.t (MacroID int identity, MacroText varchar(max))
go
-- populate the table
insert into dbo.t (MacroText)
values ('[Version] 3.5.1.212
[Description] TaxLot information for populating Holdings table
[Portfolios] @master
[Mode] Management
[AutoPrint] No
[Graph] No
[Sheet] No
[Attended] No
[Apply Copies] No
[Page Number By] Report
[Number One Page Reports] No
[Consolidate Composites] Both
[Frames] Yes
[Output File] TxLotExt
[Error File] TxLotExt
[Report]  txlotext.rep Report txlotext.rep
$prifile 123103
$_outfile TxLotExt.xml
gauge 2 1
prop MB
frame g1 2 c y y y "Report txlotext.rep" y - y y 0 0 100 100 000000 ffffff 0 1 "" ffffff 000000 360 0 0 6a240a n
frame g0 2 r n n y "Report txlotext.rep" y - y y 0 0 100 100 000000 ffffff 0 1 "" ffffff 000000 360 0 0 6a240a n
')


-- query
select substring(macrotext, charindex('[Report]', macrotext)+len('[Report]')
,  charindex(char(0x0d), macrotext, charindex('[Report]', macrotext) ) - charindex('[Report]', macrotext) - len('[Report]'))
from dbo.t
```